# How to make an image fade in and another fade out with one button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, mouseclick-event

**I'm trying to fade in the blue square with the first click of the button. And then on the second click, the blue square fades out and the red one fades in.**

As you can see when you test it, it doesn't work that way. I don't know where I am wrong and If anyone can show me how to fix it I'd appreciate it.

```js
var currentscene = 0;

function next() {
  currentscene++;
  if (currentscene = 1) {
    var element = document.getElementById("blue");
    element.classList.add("fade-in");
  }
  if (currentscene = 2) {
    var element = document.getElementById("blue");
    element.classList.add("fade-out");

    var element = document.getElementById("red");
    element.classList.add("fade-in");
  }
}
```

```css
.squareblue {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.squarered {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.fade-out {
  animation: fadeOut ease 2s
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn ease 2s
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div2 id="blue" class="squareblue"></div2>
<div2 id="red" class="squarered"></div2>

<button class="button" onclick="next()">next</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few mistakes, and a few things to improve.

Inside your `if` conditionals, you were assigning the value of `1` and `2` to the variable `currentscene` instead of using the comparison operator `==`. I added the [remainder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) operator to be able to continue the loop indefinitely.

Instead of grabbing the element from the dom each loop, I just defined the elements at the top, and continued to reference the save variable.

instead of using a css keyframes animation, I used the css `transition` property to add animation to the changing of opacity.

If you have any questions, please ask

```js
let currentscene = 0;
const blue = document.getElementById("blue");;
const red = document.getElementById("red");;

function next() {
  currentscene++;
  if (currentscene % 2 == 0) {
    blue.classList.remove("opaque");
    red.classList.add("opaque");
  }
  else if (currentscene % 2 == 1) {
    red.classList.remove("opaque");
    blue.classList.add("opaque");
  }
}
```

```css
.squareblue,
.squarered {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  transition: 1s;
}

.squareblue {
  top: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.squarered {
  top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.opaque {
  opacity: 1;
}

button {user-select: none}
```

```html
<div2 id="blue" class="squareblue"></div2>
<div2 id="red" class="squarered"></div2>

<button class="button" onclick="next()">next</button>
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, but consider that OP might be required to use animation and @keyframes

Comment: @fnostro nowhere in the question does it indicate a need to use a keyframes animation, as this would be an inappropriate use of it imo. Happy to add if OP needs.

Comment: you may well be right, it was an observation based on the question seeming more like a homework assignment than real world requirement.

Comment: @asyncawait Thank you that was very helpful. I was using square with colors only as a demonstration. In actuality, I'm trying to use images instead of them. Also I'm intending to add more "scenes" / images and don't want to loop the two (more sequential and linear) How would you go about doing both of these if it isn't too much to ask?

Comment: Never mind I was able to do it myself. Nevertheless thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @コピペマスター, glad you were able to figure it out! Good luck, happy coding 